# Help Identifying Vintage Capacitor Symbol

Tags: capacitor, diagram, symbol

I am trying to understand a vintage circuit diagram (70s) and came across this symbol of a capacitor with an arrow. Is this a bi-polar capacitor? Why show an arrow?
[image]

Comment: I suspect it's a triangle, and there's a key somewhere on the schematic or the parts list. I've never seen it as something with an inherent meaning.

Comment: Often this symbol Δ was used to refer to Notes on schematic

Answer (score 1):

That's a 10 nF capacitor.  The triangle is not a standard symbol.  It may correspond to a footnote on the schematic.  Or, it is possibly be a voltage range classification, construction type, etc.  If so, that would be listed in the corner of the schematic someplace too.

Just use common sense to determine the voltage and other requirements.  You don't show what is connected to the left of the cap.  The cap may need to be X or Y rated if it touches the power line.  However, since the right side of the diodes are at less than 63 V, this cap probably does not touch the power line.  It is probably being fed from the secondary of a transformer.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility for the triangle would be that the capacitor depicted in the image is a multi-section capacitor. Some of this capacitor designated their leads by images as shown below

[image]

And therefore the traingle there would be indicating the capacitor in the traingle lead.

Comment: **Not likely**. The capacitor clearly indicates that it's non-polarized and not an electrolytic. And .01 uF is too low a value for an electrolytic.

Comment: The section capacitor had a common line which would automatically polarized them to common line and three capacitors. Additionally the schematics show 0.01 without the mu (see the other capacitor where mu is explicitly there) which I would read as 0.01F.